# unexpected Http error ın api integration Flutter Http

Tags: api, flutter, http

Hi there I am trying to integrate an api with flutter but a strange merged. Have an idea?

It shows link includes some '%' figure but especially it does not. Where is the problem. It is a basic think to post a request an api.

```
void yap ()async
  {
    //https://www.payfast.co.za/eng/process
    //https://sandbox.payfast.co.za​/eng/process


    String url3 = "https://sandbox.payfast.co.za​/eng/process";
    //String pkistring = v1hashing(requeststr);
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    HttpClientRequest request = await httpClient.postUrl(Uri.parse(url3));

    //headers
    //request.headers.set('Accept' ,  'application/json');
        Map body = { "merchant_id" :"10000100",
                    "merchant_key" :"46f0cd694581a",
                      "amount" :"100.00",
                          "item_name" :"Test Product"} ;
    
    //body
        request.add(utf8.encode(json.encode(body)));
    
    //response cevap
        HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();
        print(response.statusCode); // baglanti yapildi mi yapilmadi mi 200 ise yapildi
        String reply = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
        //Map responseMap = json.decode(reply);
        httpClient.close();
        print("payfast ici odeme");
        print(reply);
    
      }
```

Error Text;

```
 Unhandled Exception: FormatException: sandbox.payfast.co%E2%80%8B is not a valid link-local address but contains %. Scope id should be used as part of link-local address. (at character 19)
sandbox.payfast.co%E2%80%8B
                  ^
```

Comment: How about changing `Uri.parse(url3)` into `Uri.parse(url3.trim())`.

Comment: remains the same unfortunately

Comment: Try adding 'r' to avoid special characters:    String url3 = r"https://sandbox.payfast.co.za​/eng/process";

Comment: How about changing `Uri.parse(url3) `into `Uri.parse(Uri.decodeFull(url))`

Comment: still Remains same

Comment: And also you can try Uri.http method too.

Comment: @manofknowledge Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): Illegal percent encoding in URI

Comment: Okay, Uri.http in your case it will ve Uri.https abd do not pass url with htpp or https just pass domain

Comment: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-core/Uri/Uri.http.html It is docs for Uri.http but is is same usage for https too

Comment: @manofknowledge Do you mean this   HttpClientRequest request = await httpClient.postUrl(Uri.http( "sandbox.payfast.co.za", "​/eng/process"));

Comment: Yep. That you can define uri in different variavle for cleab code sake.

Comment: If your url is https use Uri.https

Comment: Any luck ?......

Comment: Thank you. Now I can reach html response of  this site. You are really kind

Comment: Cool I will post it as an answer for other people, cause tgey are not going to read this comments :dd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Uri.https` instead of `Uri.parse`.

In case if url is http use `Uri.http`.

But the structure of both methods are same.
Docs for Uri.http:
https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-core/Uri/Uri.http.html